# comparing the date to the current date and displaying the appropriate date in cakephp

Tags: linq, cakephp

//controller logic for getting the date

```
function new temp()
       {
         $date= $this->Profile->find('all',array(
               //'conditions'=>array('Profile.DOB+interval EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW())- EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Profile.DOB)YEAR >= '=>date('Y-m-d')),
               'conditions'=>array('date(Profile.DOB+interval (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW())- EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Profile.DOB))YEAR >= '=>date('Y-m-d')),

              'fields'=>array('date(Profile.DOB+interval (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW())- EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Profile.DOB))YEAR'),
             'order' => 'date(Profile.DOB+interval EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW())- EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Profile.DOB))YEAR',
             'limit'=>1
          ));
         for each ($date as $new)
             {
              $one= $new['Profile']['DOB'];
             }
         $data= $this->Profile->find('all',array(
               'conditions'=>array('date(Profile.DOB+interval (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW())- EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Profile.DOB))YEAR) >= '=>date($one))



          ));
         $this->set('one',$data);

       }
```

can anyone help  in this please.....

this is MySQL query for getting the appropriate date,comparing with the current date to the date in the table..

```
select * from profiles
 where
 date(date(DOB+interval (year(now())-year(DOB)) year))=
 (select (date(DOB+interval (year(now())-year(DOB)) year)) from profiles
   where date(date(DOB+interval (year(now())-year(DOB)) year))>=date(now()) 
        order by date(date(DOB+interval (year(now())-year(DOB)) year)) limit 1 );
```

Comment: You want to get age of user from profiles table?

Comment: NO I need to get upcoming  Date of birth(DOB).I tried like for ex: if DOB is "1987-12-29"and"2013-12-28".I convert both into current year like "2013-12-29","2013-12-28" and then I query order by DOB

Comment: Ok...so you want sorting on the basis of date, month and year...You can ignore year becoz anyways you are converting it into current year. Am I correct?

Comment: yes... I need to display only date order by date and month

Answer (score 0):

Try this query it will give you latest date on the basis of day and month, after that you have to change year to current year using php date functions.

```
   $date= $this->Profile->find('first',array(
                  'fields'=>array('date(Profile.DOB)'),
                  'order' => 'day(Profile.DOB), month(Profile.DOB) DESC'

              ));
```

Hope it will work!